# pip upgrade package from bitbucket not working

Tags: python, pip, bitbucket

I want to **upgrade** python package that resides in private repository in bitbucket, as you would do with pypi packages. Assume that I have the package that is just behind few commits, and my ssh is perfectly working well.

I added result as [AKX pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420151/pip-upgrade-package-from-bitbucket-not-working?noredirect=1#comment124481124_70420151).

Actually the version of package stays the same. So unless I change version number, I cannot upgrade package?

```
(env) pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git --upgrade

Collecting git+ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git
  Cloning ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git/ to /private/var/folders/blabla
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git' /private/var/folders/blabla
  warning: filtering not recognized by server, ignoring
  Resolved ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git to commit random_commit_hash
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done


Requirement already satisfied: django in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (2.2.12)
Requirement already satisfied: material in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: django-filter in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (21.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (2021.3)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in ./.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django==2.2.12->mypackage==1.0.0) (0.4.2)
```

You would expect that this code will update your package, but I don't see any changes in code even if the latest commit definitely has some new codes. Note that I intentionally left out some stuffs deemed unnecessary, but you will get the idea.

I even tried to put suffix such as `master` at the end(`git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git@master`) to see if making verbose would make any effect, but in vain.

Since it's not really reproducible, the best I can do is describe the situation, so please bear with me.

Perhaps it's bitbucket issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT
I've noticed that in production script `pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git --upgrade` works fine. It does have some different log though

```
pip install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git --upgrade
Collecting git+ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git
  Cloning ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git to /random/path
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@bitbucket.org/path/to/git.git' /random/path
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: django==2.2.12 in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (2.2.12)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: material in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: django-filter in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mypackage==1.0.0) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlparse in /path/to/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from django==2.2.12->mypackage==1.0.0) (0.2.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: mypackage
  Building wheel for mypackage (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for mypackage (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for mypackage: filename=mypackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl size=4960455 sha256=44e088cf39ec635435731ef6e6b483bb6a1be64e4d86327d6c0a61672de80a49
  Stored in directory: /random/path
Successfully built mypackage
Installing collected packages: mypackage
  Attempting uninstall: mypackage
    Found existing installation: mypackage 1.0.0
    Uninstalling mypackage-1.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled mypackage-1.0.0
Successfully installed mypackage-1.0.0
```

As you see, `pip install ..` in deploy log is converted into `git clone -q`, whereas in my local `git clone --filter=blob:none -q`.

Perhaps it's due to git version difference? Git version of deployement is 1.8.3.1, whereas that of local is 2.29.1.

Comment: You're not posting what comes next – does pip say it's installing the package at all? If the package's version number is the same as the one you currently have installed, pip will think "oh, yep, got that already".

Comment: And with a `--force-reinstall` option? Not ideal, but that's more likely to install the most recent version.

Comment: And yes, I think @AKX is right on the ball there: pip looks at the *version* ID, not the commits. So it wouldn't see any changes if the version ID hasn't changed. The `--force-reinstall` is even more likely the (only?) option.

Comment: As [AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70420151/pip-upgrade-package-from-bitbucket-not-working?noredirect=1#comment124481124_70420151) pointed out, I edited my question by adding some result.

Comment: I used `--force-reinstall` and it looks like my package is updated. Will there be any harmful behavior for `--force-reinstall`?

Comment: I edited my question. Please consider having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it tedious to edit package version everytime I change a bit of codes. Instead I decided to leave the version of the package untouched and run this in shell:

```
pip uninstall -y pakcage_name && pip install git+ssh://bitbucket.org/path/to/repo.git
```

The difference between this approach and install with `--force-reinstall` is the former leaves some dependencies on the package as is, whereas the latter doesn't.